# looking forward to our tennis battle? can I say this way?

Tags: word-choice

I am sending an email to a friend/mentor. We have the same interest in tennis and during our past conversation, we said we would like to play together one day.

Is it ok to say "I am looking forward to our tennis battle"? anything wrong with the wording?

Comment: You're looking for *match*.

Comment: I know. But just want to put a bit sense of humor. Don't know if using "battle" is too much.

Comment: Oh yeah, as a little joke it's fine!

Comment: If your friend is a native speaker and knows that you are not, (s)he will probably not get the joke, but rather think you just didn’t know the right word. If you want to make sure that (s)he gets that it’s meant to be humoristic, you can say, “Looking forward to battling it out on the tennis court with you” instead. That cannot be misunderstood as simply not knowing the right word.

Answer (score 1):

A *battle* sounds aggressive rather than humorous.  How about *duel*, *match-up*, or *showdown*.

The late, great Howard Cosell used to come up with rhyming (or assonant) descriptions like "The Rumble in the Jungle" and "The Thrilla in Manila" -- they are actually funnier because they are a bit labored.  Where is your match to be held?